# One chaincode, Multiple assets

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I am trying to create a chaincode with different assets types.

Imagine that I have a chaincode where I store the users created and also the transactions where the users receive points.

How can I create a chaincode in a way that I am able to queryAllUsers and queryAllPointsTransactions? without using lists as it is available in this github https://github.com/IBM/customer-loyalty-program-hyperledger-fabric-VSCode
Because when using lists we have problems with multiple clients and with multiple transactions at the same time.

Does anyone can help me on this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

PutState the asset separately from each key, and use the function below.

[GetQueryResult](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim#ChaincodeStub.GetQueryResult)

[GetStateByRange](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim#ChaincodeStub.GetStateByRange)